# DISM: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows, boot, deployment, wds, dism

Trying to mount a wim image to add drivers.

I keep getting the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> DISM /MOUNT-WIM /WIMFILE:C:\RemoteInstall\Boot\x64\Images\boot-(4).wim /INDEX:1 /MOUNTDIR:C:S
hares

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031


Error: 2

The system cannot find the file specified.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

But I have it:

```
    Directory: C:\RemoteInstall\Boot\x64\Images


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                      
-a---         3/24/2014  11:02 AM  278953532 boot-(2).wim                                                              
-a---         6/25/2014   5:13 PM       8192 boot-(2).wim.bcd                                                          
-a---         4/25/2014   5:08 PM  263900022 boot-(3).wim                                                              
-a---         6/25/2014   5:13 PM       8192 boot-(3).wim.bcd                                                          
-a---         6/25/2014   5:13 PM  278942048 boot-(4).wim                                                              
-a---         6/25/2014   5:13 PM       8192 boot-(4).wim.bcd                                                          
-a---         3/20/2014  11:50 PM  217559035 boot.wim                                                                  
-a---         6/25/2014   5:13 PM       8192 boot.wim.bcd                                                              
-a---         6/25/2014   2:25 PM  234786548 windows-image-capture.wim                                                 
-a---         6/25/2014   5:13 PM       8192 windows-image-capture.wim.bcd
```

Any idea as to what the cause could be?

Comment: What is in the dism.log?  The web seems to indicate that it could be another file item, a dependancy for the program?

Comment: Add "" around the filename after /WIMFILE:. does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Check your path C:\Shares  you had C:Shares.